# Хендмейд или рукоделие?

Tags: стилистика

Мне нужен совет.
Я довольно много пишу о ручной работе, но всегда называю это занятие "хендмейд", потому что слово "рукоделие" ассоциируется у меня с кисейной барышней, только и умеющей, что сидеть у окна, вздыхать и вышивать голубков))). Но это, конечно, мой личный глюк. А что посоветуют знатоки русского языка: как лучше писать все-таки: хендмейд или рукоделие?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Ремесло", мне кажется, не вариант. Например, разновидность хендмейда — мыловарение или скрапбукинг (оформление альбомов или открыток ручной работы). Какое уж тут ремесло? Я бы предложила просто "ручная работа". А как вы считаете?

Comment: Да, ручная работа. Просто ремесло в глобальном плане и есть ручная работа, противопоставляясь промышленному производству (на фабрики с технологическим конвейером)

Comment: И мне нравится. Ручная работа. И сразу понятно. Я, например, ни разу не слышала ни "хендмейд", ни "скрапбукинг", а услышала бы - сразу не поняла. Так все слова можно заменить, а зачем? Если есть понятное русское слово или словосочетание. Да и очень неудобны в произношении эти слова.

Comment: Ну, для скрапбукинга, увы, русского слова нет. Это интересное направление пришло к нам из-за границы и так и осталось с английским названием. Я сама не поклонница англицизмов в русском языке, но тут даже не могу придумать какого-то русского термина для этого слова.  
Кстати, можно вынести это в отдельный вопрос — авось народ что-то подскажет. Как считаете?

Comment: >Я бы предложила просто "ручная работа". А как вы считаете?  
  
Только как определение: "Изделие ручной работы". Ну и когда по контексту не вызывает сомнения, что работа=изделме.

Comment: "Ну, для скрапбукинга, увы, русского слова нет" - ну объяснили же вы словосочетанием: оформление альбомов ручной работы. Обязательно нужно сказать одним словом? А как тогда сказать одним словом: обучение русскому языку7

Answer (score 2):

Рукоделие. Однозначно.

Comment: Слишком короткий ответ. Обоснуйте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Не согласен с рукоделием. Рукоделие - именно, обычно, подразумевает работу с тканью, нитками, шерстью. Я же предлагаю вариант - "народные промыслы" в случае если используются какие-то традиционные технологии. Ну, или просто "ремесло".

Answer (score 1):

Оба слова можно использовать, для разнообразия. 
*Хендмейд* больше подходит для обозначения полученного изделия, особенно если нужно подчеркнуть его современность, модность.

Comment: Соглашусь с тем, что хендмейд подразумевает законченное изделие, результат. А вот процесс, получается, должен быть хендмейдингом? Звучит кривовато, но аналогичные заимствованные слова в русском имеются.

Comment: А  зачем ?  Вообще  не  вижу  смысла  в  этом  заимствовании.  Выбор  нужного  слова  из  традиционного  набора  русских  слов  точнее  раскроет  характер  изделия.

Comment: По поводу хендмейдинга - да, я тоже не вижу смысла в таком заимствовании. Рукоделие, ручная работа, ремесло. Если же говорить про конкретные виды занятий, то не всегда им есть аналог в русском языке.

Answer (score 0):

Надо бы поподробнее о предмете... Я так и не понял до конца, о чем это вы пишете.
"Ручная работа" может означать все что угодно, вплоть до сборки элементов синхрофазотрона или сбора малины в дедушкином саду.

Слово же handmade во-первых не столь популярно в английском, как это может показаться знакомым с его постоянным использованием в русском, а во-вторых, при всем том - довольно многозначное. Об всех оттенках значений я даже не рискну рассуждать, но, боюсь, "русское" значение - не главное...

Могу только предположить, что речь идёт о всякого рода непрофессиональных занятиях по изготовлению "авторских" сувениров, украшений, приспособлений. Тогда в отношении изготовления чего-либо с помощью иголок, ниток, вязальных спиц и прочего сделанных, то "рукоделие" (как процесс) вполне приемлемо. Можно ли назвать "рукоделием" *результат* такого занятия - даже не знаю. В отношении же всех остальных занятий (процесса), даже не знаю, есть ли общее слово... Для самих же изделий могу предложить только "поделки".

Comment: А почему слово "авторские" взято в кавычки? Это действительно авторские работы, которые, как правило, дают сто очков вперед заводской штамповке.  
А слово "поделки" четно ассоциируется со школьными уроками труда, что для меня, как человека, занимающимся разными видами рукоделия, просто оскорбительно. Люди делают настоящие шедевры - и по сложности, и по красоте! И назвать это "поделками" - все равно, что назвать "куколкой" Давида Микеланджело!

Comment: Слово  "авторские"  по  отношению  к  сувенирам  может  употребляться  и  с  кавычками  и  без  кавычек. Зависит  от  контекста.  Насчёт  "поделок"  согласен  с  вами  полностью.  Вопрос  не  по  теме:  бегемотус  где ?

Comment: Понятия не имею. Возможно, сменил ник.))

Comment: >Вопрос не по теме: бегемотус где ?  
  
В бане парится.

Comment: "Вопрос не по теме: бегемотус где ?" - здесь. Сменил ник и имидж: стал аккуратнее в высказываниях и внимательно, без прежнего нагромождения орфографических ошибок отвечает. Но темп не теряет. Молодец!

Comment: Бегемотусы не меняются. Меняется к ним отношение.

Comment: Думаю,  что  в  отношении  авторской  песни,  слово  "авторский"  не  считается  переносным.

Comment: В отношении песни - нет вопросов. Там кавычки неуместны.

Comment: >В бане парится.

Бан, похоже, бессрочный.))))
Но Вы всё равно узнаваемы с первой фразы.))